# Left position property of the handle in noUiSlider

Tags: css, nouislider

I am trying to get the current left property value of the div handle of noUiSlider as I slide. But I am getting always its initial left property value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

  noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [1],
    connect: true,
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 10
    }
  });

  slider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function() {
    var handle = $("div.noUi-handle");
    $(leftPosition).text(($(handle).position().left));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.0.0/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.0.0/nouislider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
</div>
<div id="leftPosition"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `slide` event gets 5 arguments: `values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions`.

The 5th `positions` argument contains the left positions, in percentages.